# Uninstall phpstorm 7.1 on ubuntu to install phpstorm 8

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

title says it all i want to uninstall phpstorm so i can upgrade but i cant figure out how. I have tired doing `sudo apt-get remove phpstorm` and also with the version number but it doesn't work.

I have also tried the synaptic package manger but still cant find phpstorm storm i have tried jet brains and phpstorm as well.

What can i do to remove it competently, should i just delete all of the files it is located in? Also what is the package name for phpstorm so made i can remove it with `sudo apt-get remove 'packageName'`

Appreciate all of the help thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is easy to complete uninstall phpstrom any version in Ubuntu . follow this instruction

1. enter your home directory
2. here you see .WebIde100 ( if it is hidden click ctrl + H to show hidden file)
3. there open terminal and delete this folder the command is
   **sudo rm -rf .WebIde100/**
4. then install your any version
5. enjoy and happy coding

Comment: after removing folder if i try to reinstall php storm, when it opens it quickly ask for upgrade or close.

Answer (score 13):

You need only delete the directory installation, in my case the directory is:

> use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to reveal hidden folders.

```
$rm -r ~/.PhpStorm2016.1
```

delete this directory and delete the script **pstorm**

```
$sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pstorm
```

you can find **pstorm** using

```
$whereis pstorm
```

Comment: for phpstorm 2018 , its $sudo rm /usr/local/bin/phpstorm instead of pstorm

Answer (score 12):

1. sudo snap list
2. sudo snap remove phpstorm

This is best way. If you install phpstorm without snap, it will still work.

snap commands at ubuntu. [Snap commands list](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy)

Answer (score 7):

On Linux, PhpStorm doesn't get installed through apt. You had to have extracted the .tar.gz file to a directory, then run it from there (with the option of creating some shortcuts afterwards).

When you upgrade to a new version of PhpStorm, the suggestion is simply to install the newest version to a completely empty directory (rather than overwriting an older directory).

You can run `find ./ -name phpstorm.sh` from your home directory (assuming you installed it within your home directory, to find where it was extracted to. It will usually be into a folder called "PhpStorm-13#.#/bin", depending on the version 7.1 internal version number.

My results (PhpStorm 8):

`$ find ./ -name phpstorm.sh
./JetBrains/PhpStorm-138.2001.2328/bin/phpstorm.sh`

Comment: Okay now i have installed phpstorm 8 but no icon is created for it i have to run .sh everytime how can i fix this?

Comment: never mind i have fixed it i understood what you meant now, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

If for any reason you want to uninstall PhpStorm, simply delete /opt/phpstorm/ directory and all subdirectories and files in it.

sudo rm /opt/phpstorm/ -R